# Emphasize a specific UI component

Tags: apache-flex, user-interface, flex4

I'd like to add visual emphasis to a selected UI component by de-emphasizing everything around it, e.g. make everything around it blurry, or more transparent, or something similar.

Two questions, really:

- spec: what effect would you use do build something like this? Do you know of any software that does this well?
- implementation: what is the most obvious approach to apply a blur, or change alpha, to everything around a specific component?

thank you all!

Comment: you should try http://ui.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you display the component using the PopUpManager, everything else will 'blur' out on it's own.  You won't be able to interact with it, though.

I you don't want to use PopUpManager, then manually disable everything but the component you want to highlight.  This could be dead simple, or could be horribly complex depending on your architecture and how components are laid out in relation to the component you want to highlight.

If you don't want to disable a component, but do want the disabled 'look', then most Spark components have 'disabled' SkinState.  You could copy the design to the active state, or create a new state for your "not de-activated even though it looks like' state.

Comment: IMHO a modal window is the way to go. if on the other hand you only want to focus the user's attention on some part of the ui, look at what is done here in StackOverflow: a short burst of yellow that fades to white.

Comment: @Dan where does Stack Overflow use a burst of yellow that fades to white?

Comment: @Flextras: go to the StackExchange link at the top left, open the inbox and click on a message. you'll be directed to the part of the question relevant; you'll see the background flash to yellow and quickly fading to white

Comment: @Dan I never noticed that before.  Thanks

Comment: PopupManager won't do for me in this situation - the component is already there and I just want to de-emphasize the rest - think of the isolation mode in Adobe Illustrator. The other two options make sense. I'm curious if you think an alternative could be to use some masks to cover the areas around the focused object, especially if the object is geometrically simple (say a rectangle). Thank you so far!

Comment: @fred august it sounds like it may be a viable alternative. There are often lots of routes to an end point.